# iOS UIScrollView/UITableView contentOffset gets reset when pushViewControllerAnimated:

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, contentoffset

I have a simple `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` as its `view`'s `subview`. I want to have the option to hide the `tableViewHeader` of my tableview. This is working fine - I can adjust the content offset with the height of the headerView and its all good. However, when I am to transition to a new VC (by pushing) - during the transition animation the tableView's contentOffset gets reset to {0,0} - essentially showing the header view.

Is there a way I can keep the `contentOffset` of the tableView until the new VC has been shown on screen ?

I noticed that if the contentSize of the tableView is larger than the superview's bounds (i.e. there are more cells than the frame can display) - then the `contentOffset` does not get reset. I have a log of `self.tableView.contentOffset.y` at `viewDidDisappear` - in the first instance(when the contentSize is smaller) - the log prints `0`, if that is not the case - then it prints `44` (which is the expected value). ?

**UPDATE:**

Setting the required contentOffset values in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` seems to work fine although I do not understand the implications of doing it like this. Unfortunately this does not work on iOS 7, and the expected behaviour is achieved only on iOS 8.

Comment: It might be easier to hide the header by removing it from the table, rather than scrolling so it's not visible.

Comment: I want the header to appear once the user scrolls to top...

Comment: Can you hide the header immediately before you do the push?

Comment: you cant ? its not initialized before `viewDidLoad` is it ?

Comment: I mean, in the first VC's viewWillDisappear or something.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean but unfortunately it doesn't work. Seems like the offset reset happens after `viewWillDisappear` and before `viewDidDisappear`

Comment: Maybe... explicitly scroll the view up during viewWill/DidDisappear using scrollRectToVisible:animated:?

Comment: Setting the contentOffset in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` seems to fix the problem. I don't understand why and whether its a good idea though...